# Split keyboard moving offscreen

Tags: ios, ipad, keyboard

I have a very strange bug that I can't fix. It is related to UITextField and Split Keyboard. When any textfield (say Email textfield) becomes a first responder then keyboard appears just fine. But when you select another textfield (say password) then keyboard is moving downwards and below the screen. If you touch again any other input field then keyboard disappears forever. I cannot change the frame of keyboard so I can do nothing about it. If you know about this issue and know how to avoid it please tell me. I'm using iPad 4th gen iOS 6, this bug also happens on both iOS Simulators ios 5.1 and ios 6.1.
I have also tried empty UIViewController with just UITextfields on it.

[image: Split keyboards partially hidden]

Comment: You'll need to provide code with some concrete explanations of your view hierarchy

Comment: This is not a bug but new feature on above IOS 5.

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD excuse me? keyboard moving off-screen and therefore becoming unusable is a feature? Or was it a sarcasm attempt?

Comment: @ren6 don't you love how all people answering don't notice that problem is not "split keyboard", but "keyboard moving offscreen"? :)

Comment: @Stavash I've tried with empty UIViewController and UITextfield on it.
This bug doesn't happen on new Project. There is something wrong with the project settings, I guess.

Comment: Have you done any gesture handling in your code?

Comment: If you can create a small test project demonstrating this behavior (ideally with all code confined to the view controller), it would be helpful.